# Not able to fetch user info using token : Octokit

Tags: javascript, octokit-js

I have created a chrome plugin to fetch the list of user, I am using `Octokit`

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(getDataFromPopup);
function getDataFromPopup(message){
    const apiUrl = message.apiUrl;
    const apiToken = message.apiToken;

    console.log('apiToken -> '+apiToken);
    console.log('apiUrl -> '+apiUrl);
    const objOctokit = new Octokit({
        auth: 'token '+apiToken,
        // set custom URL for on-premise GitHub Enterprise installations
        baseUrl: apiUrl,
        request: {
            timeout: 0
        }
    });


    objOctokit.users.list().then(function (objResult) {
        debugger;
       alert(objResult);
    });
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(getDataFromPopup);  //optional
}
```

I am giving the token from the developer settings and the url as `https://api.github.com` but the return is a list of 30 users which I dont even know.

Am in using `Octokit` correctly?

[image]

Expected : Only my User details.

Actual : List of 30 random users. As shown in image .

Comment: What are you trying to do? What was the expected result?

Comment: expected result would be to get the my username based on the token passed. for eg: when we hit rest api with token it should return me the result containing my username, but instead it return list of random users as shown above.

Comment: Please update your question with those details, you'll get better responses to your questions if you do https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `octokit.users.list()` which lists all users.

> Lists all users, in the order that they signed up on GitHub. This list includes personal user accounts and organization accounts.

To get the currently authenticated user

```js
octokit.rest.users.getAuthenticated()
```

For more about the users routes, check out the [documentation](https://octokit.github.io/rest.js/v18#users-get-authenticated).